# How to check if abc == sqrt(a^b^c) very fast (preferably Python)?

Tags: python, performance, math

Let a,b,c be the first digits of a number (e.g. 523 has a=5, b=2, c=3). I am trying to check if abc == sqrt(a^b^c) for many values of a,b,c. (Note: abc = 523 stands for the number itself.)

I have tried this with Python, but for a>7 it already took a significant amount of time to check just one digit combination. I have tried rewriting the equality as multiple logs, like log_c[log_b[log_a[ (abc)^2 ]]] == 1, however, I encountered Math Domain Errors.

---

**Is there a fast / better way to check this equality (preferably in Python)?**

Note: Three digits are **an example** for StackOverflow. The goal is to test much higher powers with seven to ten digits (or more).

---

Here is the very basic piece of code I have used so far:

```
for a in range(1,10):
    for b in range(1,10):
        for c in range(1,10):
            N = a*10**2 + b*10 + c
            X = a**(b**c)
            if N == X:
                print a,b,c
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote... :( if the question needs improvement or is misplaced, please give appropriate feedback

Comment: You only need to check for 3 digit numbers?

Comment: No, but as an example I choose 3 digits, higher powers are the goal (but python already fails with 3 digits)

Comment: `N = a*10**2 + b*10**1 + c`

Comment: @DanielLee yes, sorry for the typo

Comment: 3 ^ 9 ^ 9 already has about 184846550 digits if my math is correct...

Comment: "I have tried this with Python, but quickly ran into Value Errors. " *what errors exactly*? If you are getting errors, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do? There are only 999 possible numbers matching your "abc" scheme - when approaching this very naively - just brute-force it once (via multiprocessing, PyPy, cython, numpy, numba,...) and hardcode/cache the result set.

Comment: Also figure out why you are getting the errors and whether or not that has impact on getting your answers (pretty sure `999` will not satisfy as a possible answer, so don't even bother making that calculation, as an example)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi brute-forcing takes (with the code posted in the question) a long time! How to make this brute-force algorithm faster? If I find a good solution for three digits, my goal is to generalize it for numbers with much more digits

Comment: Have you made any considerations on *reduction* of computation instead of *speed*? E.g. Have you worked out any properties to reject numbers that don't work? For example, if XY11 is larger than 9999 you don't have to check XY12 etc.

Comment: @FabianSchn. So your goal is not *actually* to compute the abc, but instead the (a1, a2,...)? What realistically is an upper bound? Do they fit a machine integer?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes correct, I was looking forward to testing numbers with 7-10 digits

Comment: This is not a problem amenable to brute force searching, especially for larger numbers of digits.   Do some real math, determine the likely range of a^b^c^d^... and then realise that there are probably no solutions.

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks, however, there are definitely solutions for six digits, I know of one solution

Comment: I imagine that six digit number mostly contains zeroes and ones.

Comment: Yes, that one in the middle makes all the digits to its right moot.   This is what was alluded to in the other comments that mentioned reducing the problem space instead of brute forcing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are uselessly calculating very large integers, which can take much time as Python has unlimited size for them.

You should limit the values of `c` you test.

If your largest possible number is 1000, you want `a**b**c < 1000**2`, so `b**c < log(1000**2, a) = 2*log(1000, a))`, so `c < log(2*log(1000, a), b)`

Note that you should exclude a = 1, as any power of it is 1, and b = 1, as b^c would then be 1, and the whole expression is just a.

To test if the square root of a^b^c is abc, it's better to test if a^b^c is equal to the square of abc, in order to avoid using floats.

So, the code, that (as expected) doesn't find any solution under 1000, but runs very fast:

```
from math import log

for a in range(2,10):
    for b in range(2,10):
        for c in range(1,int(log(2*log(1000, a), b))):
            N2 = (a*100 + b*10 + c)**2
            X = a**(b**c)
            if N2 == X:
                print(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 0):

`a**(b**c)` will grow quite fast and most of the time it will far exceed three digit number. Most of the calculations you are doing will be useless. To optimize your solution do the following:

- Iterate over all 3 digit numbers
- For each of these numbers square it and is a power of the first digit of the number
- For those that are, check if this power is in turn a power of the second digit
- And last check if this power is the third digit

Comment: I don't think that generates all the potential solutions, as the three digit number doesn't need to be a square; it needs to be a square root, which doesn't exclude any integers.

Comment: Hmm my bad. Taking another look OP is not checking for square or sqrt at all in the current implementation. I will adapt my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for numbers whose square root is equal to a three-digit integer. That means your `X` has to have at most 6 digits, or more precisely `log10(X) < 6`. Once your `a` gets larger, the potential solutions you're generating are much larger than that, so we can eliminate large swathes of them without needing to check them (or needing to calculate `a ** b ** c`, which can get very large: `9 ** 9 ** 9` has `369_693_100` DIGITS!).

`log10(X) < 6` gives us `log10(a ** b ** c) < 6` which is the same as `b ** c * log10(a) < 6`. Bringing it to the other side: `log10(a) < 6 / b ** c`, and then `a < 10 ** (6 / b ** c)`. That means I know I don't need to check for any `a` that exceeds that. Correcting for an off-by-one error gives the solution:

```
for b in range(1, 10):
    for c in range(1, 10):
        t = b ** c
        for a in range(1, 1 + min(9, int(10 ** (6 / t)))):
            N = a * 100 + b * 10 + c
            X = a ** t
            if N * N == X:
                print(a, b, c)
```

Running this shows that there aren't any valid solutions to your equation, sadly!